# Break up XML data from Ajax call with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have a loooong list of data from an XML file that I'm formatting into an unordered list. I'd like to break up the data into multiple lists so I can format them into columns with CSS. Is there a way I can interject a `</ul><ul>` every 20 records or so?

Here's what my AJAX/jQuery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "lang-select.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var countries = $('div.countries ul');
            $(xml).find('dropdown').each(function(){
                $(this).find('country').each(function(){
                    var url = $(this).attr('url');
                    var label = $(this).text();
                    countries.append("<li><a href='"+ url +"' style='background-image: url(images/" + label.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase() + ".jpg);'>" + label + "</a></li>");
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's the demo as it is currently.](http://tomryandesign.com/dev/languages/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest/most elegant approach would be to chunk your list of countries `$(this).find('country')` into an an array of fixed length arrays.

Then, nest a couple loops to iterate the arrays, building a list for each array.

EDIT: So your code created a bunch of items in a single list as it was.  What you need to do is find out when every 20th item happens, the simplest way, would be to break up your array, something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "lang-select.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var countriesList = $('div.countries ul');
        var countriesListItems = [];

        $(xml).find('dropdown').each(function(){
            $(this).find('country').each(function(){
                var url = $(this).attr('url');
                var label = $(this).text();
                var listItem = $("<li><a href='"+ url +"' style='background-image: url(images/flags/" + label.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase() + ".jpg);'>" + label + "</a></li>");

                countriesListItems.push(listItem);                
            });
        });

        var chunkedCountriesListItems = chunk(countriesListItems, 20);

        var currentList = countriesList;
        $.each(chunkedCountriesListItems, function() {
            $.each(this, function() {
                currentList.append(this);
            });
            countriesList.after(currentList);
            currentList = $('<ul />');
        });
    }
});

function chunk(arr, len){
    for(var x, i = 0, c = -1, l = arr.length, n = []; i < l; i++)
        (x = i % len) ? n[c][x] = arr[i] : n[++c] = [arr[i]];
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Um... I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that. I'm a beginner with this jQuery stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but that stopped it from rendering any items from the XML at all.

Comment: @Tom, time to debug.  Check that `countriesListItems` has values before the call to `chunk`.  Then check that `chunkedCountriesListItems` has values afterwards.  And add some alerts to the `$.each` loops to see if it is actually looping.  Lastly, check that `countriesList.after(currentList);` is working.  It is supposed to be adding a new `<ul />` after the previous one it created.

Comment: Okay, I added alerts going down the line until something new became observable. When I put it after `$.each(this, function() {` then the list items start appearing one by one, but disappear when the last of the first chunk should appear (I reduced the number in each chunk to 5 to expedite watching it happen). Go here to see: http://tomryandesign.com/dev/languages/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(xml).find('dropdown').each(function(){

    var $countries = Math.ceil($('country', this).length); // country amount found in this dropdown

    var groups = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < $countries; i++)
    {
        var url = $('county:eq('+i+')', this).attr('url'); // eq(number) - finds the item at that index
        var label = $('country:eq('+i+')', this).text();

        if(i%20 == 0) groups += '<ul>';
        groups += "<li><a href='"+ url +"' style='background-image: url(images/flags/" + label.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase() + ".jpg);'>" + label + "</a></li>";
        if(i%20 == 19 || i == $countries-1) groups += '</ul>';

    }

    countries.append(groups);
});
```